# Combining CPU-bound and IO-bound work in async method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

There is such application:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HandleRequests(10).Wait();
        HandleRequests(50).Wait();
        HandleRequests(100).Wait();
        HandleRequests(1000).Wait();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async Task IoBoundWork()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

    private static void CpuBoundWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    private static async Task HandleRequest()
    {
        CpuBoundWork();
        await IoBoundWork();
    }

    private static async Task HandleRequests(int numberOfRequests)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(HandleRequest());
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }
```

Below the output of this app:

[image]

From my perspective having CPU-bound and IO-bound parts in one method it is quite regular situation, e.g. parsing/archiving/serialization of some object and saving that to the disk, so it should probably work well. However in the implementation above it works very slow. Could you please help me to understand why?

If we wrap the body of CpuBoundWork() in Task it significantly improve performance:

```
    private static async Task CpuBoundWork()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(100));
    }

    private static async Task HandleRequest()
    {
        await CpuBoundWork();
        await IoBoundWork();
    }
```

[image]

Why it works so slow without Task.Run? Why we can see performance boost after adding Task.Run? Should we always use such approach in similar methods?

Comment: Note that in addition to answers below - reordering IO and CPU operations (so that `await IoBoundWork()` is first) also helps, because continuation in console application will be scheduled to thread pool thread (and to be safe in non-console applications you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)`). In real world you often do it like this - first IO (get something to work on), then CPU bound work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRequests; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(HandleRequest());
    }
```

The returned task is created at the first `await` in the `HandleRequest()`. So you are executing all CPU bound code on one thread: the `for` loop thread. complete serialization, no parallelism at all.

When you wrap the CPU part in a task you are actually submitting the CPU part as Tasks, so they are executed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing, this is what happens:

```
|-----------HandleRequest Timeline-----------|
|CpuBoundWork Timeline| |IoBoundWork Timeline|
```

Try doing it like this:

```
private static async Task HandleRequest()
{
    await IoBoundWork();
    CpuBoundWork();
}
```

It has the advantage of starting the IO work and while it waits, the CpuBoundWork() can do the processing. You only await at the last moment you need the response.

The timeline would look somewhat like this:

```
|--HandleRequest Timeline--|
|Io...
   |CpuBoundWork Timeline|
      ...BoundWork Timeline|
```

On a side note, open extra threads (Task.Run) with caution in an web environment, you already have a thread per request, so multiplying them will have a negative impact on scalability.

Answer (score 0):

You've indicated that your method *ought* to be asynchronous, by having it return a `Task`, but you've not actually made it (entirely) asynchronous.  You're implementation of the method does a bunch of expensive, long running, work synchronously, and *then* returns to the caller and does some other work asynchronously.

Your callers of the method, however, assume that it's *actually* asynchronous (in entirety) and that it doesn't do expensive work synchronously.  They assume that they can call the method multiple times, have it return immediately, and then continue on, but since your implementation *doesn't* return immediately, and instead does a bunch of expensive work before returning, that code doesn't work properly (specifically, it's not able to start the next operation until the previous one returns, so that synchronous work isn't being done in parallel).

Note that your "fix" isn't quite idiomatic.  You're using the async over sync anti-pattern.  Rather than making `CpuBoundWork` `async` and having it return a `Task`, despite being a CPU bound operation, it should remain as is an `HandleRequest` should handle indicating that the CPU bound work should be done asynchronously in another thread by calling `Task.Run`:

```
private static async Task HandleRequest()
{
    await Task.Run(() => CpuBoundWork());
    await IoBoundWork();
}
```